# Spring boot: Consider defining a bean of type 'com.repository.services.interfacename' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've deployed an spring boot application, where i created an interface and implement it with two classes.

```
public interface interfacename {
    LinkedHashSet<String> names(String path);
}
```

And implemented classes are

```
@Component
public class class1 implements interfacename {
......
}

@Component
public class class2 implements interfacename {
......
}
```

Now i try to create an instance for both the classes using interface name,

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("class1")
interfacename imp1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("class2")
interfacename imp2;
```

It is the configuration class,

```
@Configuration
public class interfacenameConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "class1", matchIfMissing = true)
    public interfacename class1Service() {
        return new class1();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "stanfordname")
    public interfacename class2Service() {
        return new class2();
    }
}
```

My Project structure is,

```
com.repository
    application.java(@SpringApplcation)
com.repository.controller
    applicationcontroller.java(@RestController)
com.repository.services
    interfacename.java
    interfacenameconfig.java(@configuration)
    class1.java(@component)
    class2.java(@component)
```

It throws the following error
Action:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.repository.services.interfacename' in your configuration.
```

please someone guide me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ok it is mispelled.

Comment: Can you post your configuration class? Do you use `@ComponentScan` annotation?

Answer (score 3):

In you're usage you're saying that you want beans with the ids / names `class1` and `class2`respectively:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("class1")
interfacename imp1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("class2")
interfacename imp2;
```

But in the configuration you gave them different names:

```
@Configuration
public class interfacenameConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "class1", matchIfMissing = true)
    public interfacename class1Service() {
        return new class1();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "stanfordname")
    public interfacename class2Service() {
        return new class2();
    }
}
```

Namely: `class1Service` and `class2Service`. Those Ids are derived from the name of the function instantiating the beans

Two possible fixes:

1. Give them the names you want with `@Bean("class1")` and `@Bean("class2")`.

OR

2. Use the names they have in the qualifier, that is: `@Qualifier("class1Service")` and `@Qualifier("class2Service")`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had the same problem and I was able to solve it by defining the bean related implementations of my classes.

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration class you should have an annotation to prompt for component scanning to the package that your interface `interfacename` belongs.

E.g.:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.repository.services"})
```

In Spring-boot you usually have this annotation in the Spring boot application class

e.g.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.repository.services"})
public class MyApplication {

}
```

**UPDATE**

If you have multiple classes implementing an interface you can use the `value` attribute when annotating them as `@Component`

```
@Component(value="class1")
public class class1 implements interfacename 

@Component(value="class2")
public class class2 implements interfacename
```

and then `@Autowire` them with `@Qualifier` as you already do.

Based on your last update, since the @SpringBootApplication is in the parent directory of your spring-managed beans I think you can omit the `@ComponentScan` annotation. Spring will scan by default all the sub-packages below `com.repository`.

However I still believe that the `interfacenameconfig` class is redundant. Why are you declaring the same beans as the ones you have annotated as `@Component`? Either `@Component` or `@Bean`, there is no reason having both for the same beans as far as I know and it could probably be the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  but my main class located in "com.repository" directory. So is it mandatory to mention the componentscan annotation in the application class.

Comment: Although I do not understand your comment, in my example above the `ComponentScan` annotation is indeed in the application class `MyApplication`. Moreover since you annotate your `class1`, `class2` with `@Component` I think you should not place them as `@Beans` in this `interfacenameConfig` class.

Comment: ok. after adding the services parameter, it is not scanning the controller. So after adding the controller part it throws 

    Field org1 in com.repository.controller.Controller required a 
    bean of type 'com.repository.services.interfacename' that could not be 
    found.

Comment: Update your question and post more info, I am not supposed to know what your project setup, packages etc lookalike. Application class, controller and any other configuration class or file are necessary to spot the problem. I think the `interfacenameConfig` is kinda wrong if it only creates those two beans, since they are already annotated with `@Component` and Spring should treat them correctly. If you do want to use the `interfacenameConfig` I think you should rename the `@Qualifier("class1")` to `@Qualifier("class1Service")` and the `@Qualifier("class2")` to `@Qualifier("class2Service")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @Service annotation above interface implementation.

e.g. `@Component
      public interface interfacename {
      LinkedHashSet<String> names(String path);
    }`

```
  @Service
  public class interfaceDefinition implements interfacename{
  LinkedHashSet<String> names(String path){
   // write code here
  }
  }
```

Comment: but you have put the `@Service` annotation above the interface not the implementation

Comment: above service, you can give `@Component` annotation and above implementation, you should give `@Service` annotation.

Comment: You are confusing "implementation" with "interface". The "implementation" of an "interface" is a concrete or abstract "class". An "interface" is never an "implementation". Probably you meant definition and not implementation. And if you have `@Component` on a class which implements an interface I think it is redundant to annotate this interface with `@Service`

Comment: @pleft - I meant definition which will implements interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have add the qualifier annotation along with @Component annotation. Then i ensure the application it is working fine.

```
@Component
@Qualifier("class1")
public class class1 implements interfacename {
......
}
```

Thanks for the reply